# Token authentication Android Studio

Tags: android, security, authentication, token

If I want to store the token retrieved from the server in a place where i can access to it from wherever in my code to keep sending it as a json header to my server, where i should store it? is there any other recommendation you can give me to use with token auth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems safe to store it in the app's private *SharedPreferences* and make a static helper to get it.
Only your app will have access to this.

[from Android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE)

> File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).

```
package net.rouk1.helper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class TokenSaver {
    private final static String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "net.rouk1.SHARED_PREF_NAME";
    private final static String TOKEN_KEY = "net.rouk1.TOKEN_KEY";

    public static String getToken(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(TOKEN_KEY, "");
    }

    public static void setToken(Context c, String token) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN_KEY, token);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, just 1 more question, those methods asks for a context, is that the app context? like.. ` PrefsSaver tokensaver = new PrefsSaver();
        tokensaver.setToken(getApplicationContext(), user.getToken());

Comment: Yes, the application's context or simply your current acivity.